# Fatal: unable to update url base from redirection when pull code

Tags: proxy, gitlab

```
$ git pull origin develop-Avaya
fatal: unable to update url base from redirect:    asked for: https://gitlab.com/Tuong_Nguyen1/OCMT.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
 redirect: https://192.168.10.200:1003/fgtauth?00c1271d2684a541
```

****i can't set proxy git...what should i do ?****

Answer (score 1):

Check what `git remote -v` returns for the entry `origin`:

The URL should be just: `https://gitlab.com/Tuong_Nguyen1/OCMT.git`